# How to write query with joins in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii

I want to write the following query in yii:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_leaves as tl,tbl_users_master as um
WHERE tl.user_id = um.user_id AND YEAR(tl.leave_from_date) = YEAR(NOW())
```

and I have tried to write the above query in yii as below :

```
 $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Leaves', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'with'=>'user',
            'together'=>true,
            'condition'=>'user.user_id=:user_id AND YEAR(leaves.leave_from_date)= YEAR(NOW())',
            'params'=>array(':user_id'=>$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->getId())->user_id),              
        ),
    ));
     $this->render('admin',array('model'=>$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->getId()),
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

but it throws me the following error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'leaves.leave_from_date' in 'where clause'.
```

The SQL statement executed was:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`leave_id`) FROM `tbl_leaves` `t` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_users_master` `user` ON (`t`.`user_id`=`user`.`user_id`) 
 WHERE (user.user_id=:user_id AND YEAR(leaves.leave_from_date) = YEAR(NOW()))
```

I'm new to yii, please help me how can I write the above query in yii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the look of the error all you need to do is adjust the name you used as an alias to the table

```
'condition'=>'user.user_id=:user_id AND YEAR(leaves.leave_from_date)= YEAR(NOW())',
                                                ^--------- change to t
```